# MAMP - does not show index.php

Tags: php, mamp

I have downloaded Public_html folder from a website that I have to work on and added it to MAMP > htdocs.

Then, I do type http://localhost:8888/ProjectName and it shows a blank page in state of index.php.

MAMP does not find the index.php and I can not find a way around it.

Believe, The website is using smarty (tpl.php) at some places but the index is index.php

NOTE: I have disable `// @require_once("config.inc.php");
                       // include "stored.function/db.inc";` and it seems works. How can I find the real path for them?

Comment: Then, I do type http://localhost:8888/ProjectName and it shows a blank page in state of index.php.

Comment: What does your httpd.conf look like?

Comment: If error_reporting is set to 0, then an error in your index.php will display a blank page. Could be the cause.

Comment: Try writing the full url with index.php (localhost:8888/ProjectName/index.php)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I have tried that already and it did not work

Comment: is your mamp on? what does localhost:8888/ give you?

Answer (score 2):

In default, MAMP comes with error reporting closed. You need to edit your /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini file.

Comment: I do like your idea. I am trying this right now as I have found a great post about it -> http://www.jhuskisson.com/code-tidbits/re-enabling-error-reporting-in-mamp

Comment: Üngür It is not working. It keeps showing a blank page as index.php